# Strange linux version: No headers?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am trying to write a driver. Compiling threw an error, which based on answers on here I know is due to not having linux-headers-[VERSION].

I tried apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) as suggested, but was given "Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.0.0-g5e6cec4".

This is a strange sounding name for the linux version.

How do I find compatible linux headers?

Comment: I have not used debian nor ubuntu. But in RHEL and derivatives, the header is called kernel-headers. I usually `yum install kernel-headers-$(uname -r)`.

Comment: Yes, from what I understand ubuntu and debian are the same naming convention. However, the output of `uname -r` is unusual for me, and searching the repositories for this does not locate any matchine kernel-headers package.

Comment: It means that you are running a non-standard kernel. The output of `uname -r` returns the version of the kernel that is currently running. Check how many kernels are installed and which version you expect it to be running. Maybe boot on the standard kernel? Unless there is a need to boot on this non-standard kernel (probably customized). If it is indeed customized, you probably already have the kernel-source and headers on-disk.

Comment: It looks like you are running kernel patched with cec4 http://www.mpl.ch/t10343.html